# How to write "càdlàg" and "Lévy" in Scientific workplace

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, scientific-workplace

I have two problems:

1. When I copy "càdlàg" and try to paste it to the scientific workplace, I get "cŕdlŕg"
2. I have bibliography written in JabRef but when I use it in Scientific workplace there is problem to display "Lévy" correctly

Where is the problem? Maybe I dont have some package?

Comment: What happens if you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble?

Comment: Check that all your  .tex and .bib files are  utf8 encoded and that you are compiling accordingly (i.e, **without** having some like `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` in the preamble)

Comment: @Mico This solves problem 2, but I still get "cŕdlŕg" when I paste càdlàg to the scientific workplace. In pdf I also get "cŕdlŕg"

Comment: Ok problem solved thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.